# Phpmyadmin in server not working but in local system the same works. Class 'PMA\libraries\navigation\nodes\Node' not found

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have an ubuntu server 14.04 server with Apache and php 7.

I uploaded phpmyadmin to server, not installed.

Then same works in my local machine, But fails in server.

Only chnage is that in local I have, php 5.

Error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'PMA\libraries\navigation\nodes\Node' not found in /var/www/phpmyadmin/html/libraries/navigation/NodeFactory.php on line 82
```

Can anyonw kindly please tell me a solution for the above issue.

The File is there

[image: This is a screenshot of the file direcotry from server.]

Comment: Check this maybe... https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12199

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: An uppercase directory:

```
/navigation/Nodes/Node.php
```

Even though I do not understand how this could happen - now it is working.

[Link to phpmyadmin issues of the same](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12199)